# Connecting to a database hosted on a server from within a C# project

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to connect to a database that is being hosted on my school's network within my C# project. I have tried connecting to the database like so:

```
        server = "**Server's Webaddress**";
        database = "**dbname**"; 
        uid = "**username**";
        password = "**password**";

        string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";"
            + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Is there any way that I can connect to this database hosted on the site? I am able to log into the phpmyadmin page and connect to the server using Putty.

Comment: Werent there any instruction on how to connect?  Typically that is thru an API rather than connecting directly

Comment: Going by your code, you haven't opened the connection. Mind to post the full code?

Comment: @bolkay I just have another line in there that says `connection.open()` @Disaffected 1070452 I followed this tutorial [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program)

Comment: Your connection string is a bit weird to me. The server, database, uid and password doesn't appear valid to me.

Comment: did you try my answer? replacing, password with pwd?

Comment: Spoke to one of my classmates and they said the server is a LAMP server, would that cause an issue connecting to it from C#?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get `MySqlException.number = 0` and the `MySqlException.message="Reading from the stream has failed"`

Comment: @ZackSloan Is the server host and the mysql server application configured to allow external connections to the database?

Comment: Might not be. I will check with my teacher in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the values for `SERVER`,`DATABASE`,`UID` and `PWD` are correct (I think it must be `PWD=somePassword` instead of `PASSWORD=somePassword`).

Secondly, if mysql port is not the default port, you must also specify it, like:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: tried adjusting the password to pwd. No change there